# SSRS data drive subscription with multiple formats?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

Is it possible to send multiple types of auto emails such as  MHTML and PDF? I only see 1 option to select from so i was just wondering.  Since our SSRS server is internally hosted the person being emailed can not go to the report directly to download their preference.

Comment: Sure, it is possible. Set up one subscription to send the report in MHTML, and another subscription to send the report in PDF. :) You cannot send a report out with one subscription and deliver 2 different formats.

Comment: haha thanks..... I knew that was going to be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have enterprise version, then you can use Data driven subscription and have a single subscription deliver in whatever format you want it to.
You don't need multiple subscriptions

Comment: I think he's wanting to send it in two separate formats thus requiring two different subscriptions.

Comment: I understand what the OP wants, but you can set the format of the report in the data set (for the subscription - not the report) , so you can have different formats in the same subscription.. The Render format can be sourced from the data set rather than static.  Mind you.. I'm only talking about Data Driven Subscription which is only available in Enterprise Version.

Comment: @Harry ahh I did not think of using a dataset instead of the selected drop down. Do you know what the arguments would be called?  like "MHTML,PDF" or something similar? I would like to hard code it

Comment: @TDang Yes.. I tested only two formats.. MHTML and PDF and it worked perfect.. the same (email) subscription sent me two e-mail with one as body and another as a PDF attachment... EXCEL didn't seem to work..  so just play around with what it should be named and you should be good to go.. if you do figure it out.. post it here please.

Comment: You could try looking at RSReportServer.config file.. good luck

Comment: @Harry the report does not look like it runs . This is my test query. 
     select email='test@email.com', companyid = '59',Format='PDF,MHTML'

Comment: @TDang It should be select email = 'test@email.com', companyid = '59', format = 'PDF' Union all select email = 'test@email.com', companyid = '59', format = 'MHTML' . You will have only one subscription, but it will deliver two email, one with the report as a PDF attachment and another as MHTML. If you were hoping to do both in the same e-mail.. I think you are out of luck!